# How to match Time Ranges in Java or Javascript any?

Tags: javascript, apache-nifi, ecmascript-5

I have two Data formats and need to compare them. But the prbolem is in 2nd format the Day(Mon, Tue) is in value and in 1st format it is in Variable side, So how I can compare the day.

I have to compare their contents in if else condition.Thats why need to match their formats.

First format is:

```
"B.H. MON (Mandatory)": "9:00-17:00",
```

2nd format:

```
"details": [
          {
            "data": "Mon 08:30am - 04:30pm"
          }]
```

I have tried to extract the Day and time through substring but

```
var dayFrom = details[0].data.substring(0,3);           //Mon
var amHourFrom = parseInt(details[0].data.substring(4, 2)));    //08
var amMinuteFrom = parseInt(details[0].data.substring(7,2)));   //30
var pmHourFrom = parseInt(details[0].data.substring(14, 2)));   //04
var pmMinuteFrom = parseInt(details[0].data.substring(17,2)));  //30

if(details[0].data.substring(19,2)=="pm"){
{
    pmHourFrom = hourFrom +12;      //04+12 = 16
    
}
var Str= amHourFrom+":"+amMinuteFrom"-"+pmHourFrom+":"+pmMinuteFrom;
  //Str= 08:30-16:30
```

1. how to compare the days is still a problem.
2. In above code which I have tried str has formed in "Str= 08:30-16:30" way and in 1st format there is no "0" before 9:00 am, so I also have remove that 0.

These are two problems.

And I am working in NIFI so it can be written in Java, Javascript or ecmaScript any.

Comment: What should be the output?

Comment: @NehaSoni No ouput but I have to compare them thats why I need to match their data in a particular format.

Comment: @NehaSoni I am thinking of doing it with Hashmap, to create two different hashmaps and then storing values in them, can you help in that way, because days can be back and forth like there can be no sunday in one and starts with monday while other has sunday and starts with sunday. So to keep this in mind and I thought hashmap can work

Comment: What exactly is the comparison to do? Do you mean you want a yes/no for equality? Or some result to indicate overlap? What would that comparison result be for the example input you have given? Comparison can mean many things...

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't mention the output so it's hard to generate results in a particular format.

However, you can loop through each day in the first format and find the corresponding value in the second format by extracting the day using the `slice` function.

Here is the demo-

```js
const format1 = { "B.H. SUN (Mandatory)": null, "B.H. MON (Mandatory)": "9:00-17:00", "B.H. TUE (Mandatory)": "9:00-17:00",};
const format2 = { "details": [{"data": "Mon 08:30am - 04:30pm"},{"data": "Tue 09:00am - 05:00pm"}]};

// Common slice function
const sliceF = (arg, start, end) => arg.slice(start, end)

// Main function
const compare = (format1, format2) => {
  // Loop through each day in the first format
  for (const day in format1) {
    // Find the corresponding value in the second format
    const value2 = format2.find(item => {
      return sliceF(item.data, 0, 3).toUpperCase() === sliceF(day, 5, 8)
    });
    console.log(`Match for "${day}" = `, value2 || "NOTHING")
  }
}

compare(format1, format2.details);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could determine a "standard" format, like "DAY HH:MM-HH:MM" and then convert the two types of input format to this standard format string. Then comparison becomes a matter of comparing strings.

Like this:

```js
function toString(data) {
     const [day, ...times] = data.toUpperCase().split(/[ -]+/);
     return day + " " + times.map(time => {
         let [_, h, m, ampm] = time.match(/(\d+):(\d+)(.M)?/);
         if (ampm) h = h % 12 + 12 * (ampm === "PM");
         return ("0" + h + ":" + m).slice(-5);
     }).join("-");
}

const parse = data => Array.isArray(data) 
    ? data.map(({data}) => toString(data))
    : Object.entries(data).map(([k, v]) => toString(k.split(" ")[1] + (v ? " " + v : "")));

// Example input
const obj = { "B.H. SUN (Mandatory)": null, "B.H. MON (Mandatory)": "9:00-17:00", "B.H. TUE (Mandatory)": "9:00-17:00",};
const details = [{ "data": "Mon 08:30am - 04:30pm"}, { "data": "Tue 09:00am - 05:00pm"}];

console.log(parse(obj));
console.log(parse(details));
```